# Partial/nonexact matches with LookupRows function

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, lookup

**THE PROBLEM:** LookupRows appears to be making partial matches of the third parameter (value used to match rows to return) and therefore returning the incorrect value.

**BACKGROUND:** Because of different data sources, we sometimes have users whose profile contains a "Country" value with the full country name (e.g., France, United States, Hong Kong), and other times with a two-letter ISO country code (e.g., FR, US, HK).  The rest are simply blank.  All of them *should* be the two-letter country code, so I usually include a short AMPScript (see below) to retrieve the two-letter codes when the subscriber profile contains a full country name.

Each country has a list of promotional content types that it can and cannot receive.  For example, only the US, Canada, Australia, and Hong Kong can receive certain Sale promotions.  The country names, their ISO codes, and the promotion eligibility (TRUE/FALSE) for each of 10 content types is all stored in a non-sendable data extension.

**CODE:** The AMPScript simply determines whether a country code or country name can be found in the DE and then sets the @country variable to the country code when found.  For empty and invalid values, the value defaults to 'US'.

```
%%[VAR @country_input, @country

SET @country_input = Country

IF Empty(@country_input) THEN
    SET @country = 'US'
ELSEIF RowCount(LookupRows('international_footer_specs', 'Country Code', @country_input)) > 0 THEN
    SET @country = Lookup('international_footer_specs', 'Country Code', 'Country Code', @country_input)
ELSEIF RowCount(LookupRows('international_footer_specs', 'Country Name', @country_input)) > 0 THEN
    SET @country = Lookup('international_footer_specs', 'Country Code', 'Country Name', @country_input)
ELSE
    SET @country = 'US'
ENDIF

IF @country == 'US' OR @country == 'CA' OR @country == 'AU' OR @country == 'HK' THEN

]%%

    %%=ContentAreaByName(Concat('My Contents\Dynamic\', emailname_))=%%

%%[

ENDIF

]%%
```

The problem arises in the first 'ELSEIF'.  If a user's country value is 'Austria', then it will match to 'AU' (which is the code for Australia).  Similarly, 'Estonia' matches to 'ES' (which is the code for Spain).

It appears that the LookupRows function is making partial matches because the function does the matching "in reverse".  That is, the function evaluates to 'TRUE' if the lookup value (e.g., 'Austria'), contains the entirety of the value stored in the DE (not the other way around).  So, since 'AU' is contained within 'Austria', and 'ES' is contained within 'Estonia', this function will return those respective rows for each of those lookup values even though this should be evaluating to 'FALSE'.

**BUG?:** I would expect that it should be determining whether 'Austria' is contained within 'AU', not the other way around.  After all, 'Austria' is the *lookup value*, not the value being matched against.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the documentation, but this seems to be how it *should* work.

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION:** In my case, I can avoid this scenario by switching the two 'ELSEIF' statements, which allows the country names to be searched first, which in turn avoids the pitfall of erroneously matching partial strings (i.e., the country codes) to the lookup value.  However, there are certainly instances where this could fail as well.  For example, a lookup value of 'South Sudan' or 'Nigeria' would incorrectly match to 'Sudan' or 'Niger', respectively, if those countries existed within the data extension where I store country information.

Comment: I made a quick test utilizing your example countries/codess above and your AMPScript, and it worked as expected. I suspect the issue is either with your data or this is being affected by another script somewhere else in the email.

Comment: @Gortonington: I've updated the code block above to show you the full extent of the script.  There are no other scripts or function calls in this particular email that would interfere with it.  The information in the data extension is also correct.  I've confirmed that a user with a 'Country' of 'Austria' does indeed match to the 'AU' (Australia) value by printing the subscriber's 'Country' alongside whatever ISO code it was matched to in the data extension.

Comment: The AMPScript lookup functions do not do "partial" matches -- only exact.

Comment: It _shouldn't_, but I have no other explanation for why 'Austria' matches 'AU' and 'Estonia' matches 'ES'.

Comment: I have taken the AMPscript above apart piece by piece and found no issues with it.  I believe it is an outside influence that is altering your results.  I would recommend taking apart each piece of your email/Content Area until you find which aspect was causing the incorrect result.

Comment: I don't think you are addressing the real question, which is that I'm getting partial matches and I don't know why.  Simply stating that Lookup() and LookupRows() don't make partial matches is not helpful because 1) the documentation doesn't say this explicitly, and 2) I'm clearly getting partial matches, with no obvious explanation, which is why I posted this question.  This seems to be a legitimate bug and I suspect that you're not setting up your data extension properly to be able to detect the problem that I'm describing.

Comment: I'm clearly not a power-user here, so I don't know if there's a protocol for sharing files/screenshots, but I'd like to show you all the actual data so you can see for yourselves the problem I'm encountering, and then discuss a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have today encountered this issue and finally I have managed to find the issue. The problem was that the maximum length of column was lower, therefore the LookUp was searching only for the part of the string - ie. instead of en-US it searched only for "en" and just took the first result.

Answer (score 0):

Your references to `country` and `@country` are confusing.  I think you can do this in a more simple way.  Something like this, maybe?

```
%%[

var @country, @country_input

/* returns empty string if null */ 
set @country_input = attributevalue("country") 

/* returns empty string if no value is found */
set @country = lookup('international_footer_specs', 'country code', 'country code', @country_input)

if empty(@country) then

    /* returns empty string if no value is found */
    set @country = lookup('international_footer_specs', 'country code', 'country name', @country_input)

else

   /* if no value is found after two checks, default to "US" */ 
   set @country = "US"

endif

output(concat("<br>@country_input: ", @country_input))
output(concat("<br>@country: ", @country))    

]%%
```

**EDIT**: added comments, declared `@country` variable

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71922/discussion-on-answer-by-adam-spriggs-partial-nonexact-matches-with-lookuprows-fu).